# How do I fetch time stamps of hangouts message records?

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api, google-hangouts

I'm making an app using [the Gmail REST API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview) to fetch all of my hangouts messages that are stored in the 'chats' label, but the time stamps of each message aren't in the body headers. I know that the time stamps are stored somewhere, because it shows the time of creation for each message when you hover over it in gmail.

How do I fetch time stamps of hangouts message records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Google does not provide an API for chat Hangouts. You can star this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=68) if you would like to see one. In the meantime the info available via Gmail is the best you are going to get.